# How to use different keys for different users when encrypt in Laravel?

Tags: encryption, laravel-5.7

I try to encrypt files in Laravel5.7

```
$encryptedContent = encrypt($fileContent);
```

worked for encrypt the files.

```
$decryptedContent = base64_encode(decrypt($encryptedContent));
```

worked for decrypt.

My problem is I need to use different keys for different user for encrypt the files and decrypt.
I tried the following way.

```
$crypt = new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter($newkey);
$encryptedContent = $crypt->encrypt($fileContent);
```

But it gives following error.

```
The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths
```

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Is the key 128 or 256 bits long?

Comment: Yes. App key is base64:zy1fG2idaKNqNI7JWaolANWS5hJuxTfsaDvGFFfZxj4= like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with key length.

If we use `AES-128-CBC` key should be 16 character length and `AES-256-CBC` 32 character length.